# ASPNET Identity Caching with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Ninject in an MVC application with ASPNET Identity 2.

Log in, log out, updating password etc are all working fine.  However if I update the user's name in the database, the `ApplicationUserManager` seems to be caching the user information.

This is the code to register the Identity services:

```
private void RegisterServices()
{
    kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

    var dbContext = kernel.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
    kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", dbContext);

    kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(x => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
}
```

I have posted a sample solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/aspnet-identity-cache).  `WebApplication1` works without DI, and `WebApplication2` with Ninject shows the caching behaviour.

Any advice on using ASPNET identity with DI would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, for starters you're doing dependency injection completely wrong.  You're not doing dependency injection at all.  You're doing service location, and you're bypassing all the standard DI integration points.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  The controllers all have constructor injection, and the services are registered in the composition root.  I hook the Ninject kernel into to OWIN according to the Ninject [docs](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application).  If you have an alternative pattern for using Ninject, OWIN and MVC can you post an example?

Comment: And, more importantly, you're using Ninject incorrectly.  You should simply be using the Ninject.MVC5 package, and registering your bindings in `App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs`, you would still add the UseNinjectMiddleware call in the owin startup, but configuration is handled by the NinjectWebCommon architecture.

Comment: My understanding is that the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` just bootstraps the kernel which I why I removed it.  The `Ninject.MVC5` package is there (it contains the contains the controller factory for MVC).  If I switch back to `NinjectWebCommon.cs`, how to I register the identity services in the [Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/aspnet-identity-cache/blob/master/src/WebApplication2/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L21)?  Also does the callback specified `app.CreatePerOwinContext()` not result in the kernel returning new instances on each http request?

Comment: Thanks Erik.  I tried switching back to `NinjectWebCommon.cs`, but I don't see how to wire up Ninject with OWIN and aspnet identity (see [here](https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/aspnet-identity-cache/blob/use-ninject-web-common-bootstrapper/src/WebApplication2/Startup.cs#L12) and [here](https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/aspnet-identity-cache/blob/use-ninject-web-common-bootstrapper/src/WebApplication2/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L20-L22))?

Comment: I don't think you should be using `CreatePerOwinContext` at all if you are using your own DI mechanism. At any rate, it seems pretty clear that for whatever reason `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` is not being called and that's why the name doesn't update.