# Can I substitute app.CreatePerOwinContext with IoC container

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

Default ASP.NET MVC5 template with user authentication is registering services with app.CreatePerOwinContext. Like:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<DbContext>(DbContext.Create)
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create)
```

And then in many places we can see just service locator pattern(or anti-pattern):

```
UserManager = _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

It makes code untestable and extending eg. `ApplicationUserManager` by injecting to it some custom service of course also needs service location.

Can I totally get rid of this code by using IoC container like `Autofac`, `Ninject` etc? I mean i would delete `app.CreatePerOwinContext` stuff, and register it in IoC container I use. Then I would just normally inject them to controllers/service by constructor injection.

Would it be fine to replace `app.CreatePerOwinContext` with just `container.Register` and then setting my container as a defaultdependency resolver?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this.  I tried a while ago, but ran into some issues with EF caching data (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170366/aspnet-identity-caching-with-dependency-injection).  I don't recall resolving that issue, so I'm interested to see what others think.